# Automount ext4 format thumb drive via NFS on a raspberry pi in cluster with fstab fails on reboot

Tags: debian, mount, raspberry-pi, nfs, reboot

I am trying to automount (on reboot) an NFS thumb drive onto another raspberry pies in a cluster using `fstab`.

I have tried all the solutions on how to auto mount NFS drive on reboot using `fstab`

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347996/rpi4-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-nfs-drive-not-mounting-on-boot

- `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
- `x-systemd.automount`
- `x-systemd.mount-timeout=5`
- `x-systemd.device-timeout=5`

2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405231/unable-to-mount-nfs-on-ubuntu-22-04

- `auto,vers=3`
- `_netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=10,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min`

but none of them auto mounts nfs drive after a reboot. I have to use `mount -a` after a reboot.

I am using the following distribution on all raspberry pies:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

The current `fstab` entry

`rpi1:/home/pi/cloud /home/pi/cloud nfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=5,_netdev 0 0`

Comment: there's `noauto` in there.

Comment: I have tried without it as well

Comment: a) please mention all that you've tried in your question already, what good is it if an answerer spends time recommending something you've already tried? b) you want automount, so `noauto` is clearly wrong and should be removed. c) please don't show screenshots of text, but the text instead. Your text screenshot is very small on my screen, barely legible. Copying and pasting the actual text instead of making a screenshot would both be faster and better!

Comment: sorry about it just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and non hassel solution I found is to install nfs-common package on the clients.